# в каком порядке выполняется Makefile?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

```
NAME = test
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
INC = -I ./include
FILES = test.c main.c
LIBFT = ../ft_printf/libftprintf.a
OBJ = $(addprefix build/, $(FILES:.c=.o))
SRC = $(addprefix src/, $(FILES))

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    @$(CC) -o $(NAME) $(LIBFT) $(OBJ)
build/%.o: src/%.c | build
    @$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INC) $< -o $@
build:
    @mkdir build
```

Если выполнить команду Make в каком порядке будет сборка? я думал будет выполнятся all: $(NAME) и после $(NAME): $(OBJ), но откуда make знает что нужно выполнить build/%.o: src/%.c | build
@$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INC) $< -o $@
build:
@mkdir build?

Comment: После двоеточия цели указаны зависимости. Соответственно, make будет выполнять обход графа зависимостей, выполняя его узлы. Цель `all` зависима от `$(NAME)`, `$(NAME)` зависима от `$(OBJ)`, а `$(OBJ)` - это наличие файлов с расширениями .o соответствующих файлам с расширениями .c

Comment: а $(OBJ) - это наличие файлов с расширениями .o соответствующих файлам с расширениями .c и make откуда знает что нужно выполнять build/%.o: src/%.c ?

Comment: Проверяется не только то, что файлы есть, но и то, что они новее тех файлов, от которых сами зависят. Если .o старее чем соответствующий .c, но он перекомпилируется.

Comment: я не понимаю где он в тексте ссылается на build/%.o: src/%.c, то есть про граф зависимостей я понял, в тексте все наглядно, но вот наличие файлов он сам как то проверяет? где это указано чтобы он это сделал?

Comment: Это встроено в make, любое название цели он считает именем файла. Поэтому, например, если вы создадите файл и именем `all`, то `make all` (и просто `make`) перестанет что-либо делать, ведь файл-то уже есть. Можно специально отметить, что цель не является файлом, написав что-то типа `.PHONY: all`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При запуске без параметров `make` выполняет первую цель. Хотя так говорить не правильно. `make` работает (как минимум) в два прохода: сперва отыскивает все зависимости (это вроде поиска в ширину в графе), затем выполняет команды в обратном порядке.

Итак первая цель `all`. Она зависит от пререквизита (цели) `test`. "Зависит" означает что чтобы достигнуть цели `all`, нужно достигнуть цели `test`. Здесь и далее я буду раскрывать макросы, чтобы была видна механика:

```
all: test
```

Цель `test` зависит от `build/test.o` и `build/main.o`. Чтобы достигнуть её, нужно построить два объектных файла и запустить `gcc` для сборки исполнимого модуля:

```
test: build/test.o build/main.o
    gcc -o test ../ft_printf/libftprintf.a build/test.o build/main.o
```

Цель `build/test.o` соответствует обобщенному правилу. По нему она зависит от `build/test.с` и `build`. На значок `|` пока не обращайте внимания. Обобщённое правило порождает конкретное правило:

```
build/test.o: src/test.c | build
    gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I ./include src/test.с -o build/test.o
```

Цель `build/main.o` обрабатывается аналогично:

```
build/main.o: src/main.c | build
    gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I ./include src/main.с -o build/main.o
```

Цели `src/test.c` и `src/main.c` не имеют соответствующих правил. В этой ситуации `make` убеждается что такие файлы есть на диске и помечает цели как достигнутые.

Цель `build` ни отчего не зависит, но приводит к созданию каталога `build` если его ещё не было на диске:

```
build:
    mkdir build
```

Поиск завершён. Теперь выполняем команды в обратном порядке:

```
mkdir build
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I ./include src/test.с -o build/test.o
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I ./include src/main.с -o build/main.o
gcc -o test ../ft_printf/libftprintf.a build/test.o build/main.o
```

В описании поиска в графе я опустил сравнение времен файлов. `make` сравнивает времена цели и её пререквизитов и если цель свежая, то она считается достигнутой сразу.

Вы можете попросить `make` показать какие команды от собирается исполнить (`make -n`) или объяснить почему он собирается их выполнять (`make --trace`).

В комментариях заметил важный момент. `make` все цели считает файлами на диске. Если у вас на диске окажется файл с именем `all` и дата у него будет свежее чем у `test`, то `make` посчитает что делать ничего не надо. Цели, которые "не файлы" помечайте так:

```
.PHONY: all
all: test
```